# Preferences library not loading preferences

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am using **java.util.prefs.Preferences** to create references for my application but for some reason I can't seem to load the preferences from the xml file. I'm not getting file not found errors so it's loading the file. It just doesn't seem to be parsing the file. Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong?

**Clarification** Yes the file is being loaded. The line 'root.exportSubtree(System.out)' is outputing the whole XML. However the example I took that from had it only displaying the subroot of the root 'user'. That may be a hint to my problem but I still haven't solved it.

my Preferences class

```
package com.g4apps.secure.processserver;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

public class PSPrefs {
        private String user;
        private String url;
        private String password;
        private String database;

        public PSPrefs(String file) {
            InputStream is = null;

            try {
                is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                Preferences.importPreferences(is);
                Preferences root = Preferences.userRoot();
                root.exportSubtree(System.out);
                this.user=root.get("user", "");
                this.url=root.get("url", "");
                this.password=root.get("password","");
                this.database=root.get("database","");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public String getUser() {
            return this.user;
        }
        public String getURL() {
            return this.url;
        }
        public String getPassword() {
            return this.password;
        }
        public String getDatabase() {
            return this.database;
        }


}
```

my preferences.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE preferences SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/preferences.dtd">
<preferences EXTERNAL_XML_VERSION="1.0">
    <root type="user">
        <map/>
        <node name="Server Settings">
            <map>
                <entry key="user" value="user"/>
                <entry key="url" value="jdbc:mysql://mysqldb.com/"/>
                <entry key="password" value="password"/>
                <entry key="database" value="mydb"/>
            </map>
        </node>
    </root>
</preferences>
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the thing that pops out at me is that the file is not where you think it is.  Try verifying the files existence with `file.exists()`

Make sure the file is in the correct location within the execution context

**UPDATE**

Okay, sorry my bad :(

Try this:

```
try {
    is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    Preferences.importPreferences(is);
    Preferences root = Preferences.userRoot();

    Preferences node = Preferences.userRoot().node("Server Settings");

    this.user = node.get("user", "");
    this.url = node.get("url", "");
    this.password = node.get("password", "");
    this.database = node.get("database", "");

    System.out.println(user);
    System.out.println(url);
    System.out.println(password);
    System.out.println(database);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This gives me the output of

```
user
jdbc:mysql://mysqldb.com/
password
mydb
```

Oh, and the if you were using the example from roseindia, it actually dumped the entire preferences tree, they just "highlighted" there branch

Comment: Yeah that's not it. I am reading in the xml file fine. Though the root.exportSubTree(System.out) line is displaying the whole XML. In the example I took that from it only displayed the Subtree under type=user.

Comment: @Codeguy007 Sorry, one should make sure to finish one's cup of caffeine in the morning :P

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if that was the full output or not. Looks cropped. It's not the best example as it stops before telling you how to get the values but it was the best I could find.